# Should the sharp quote should be used for the first argument of advice-add?

Tags: functions, advice, quote

... when a symbol referencing a function is actually used?

Documentation states:

> Like ‘add-function’ but for the function named SYMBOL.
>   Contrary to ‘add-function’, this will properly handle the cases where SYMBOL
>   is defined as a macro, alias, command, ...

I usually see the following around:

```
(advice-add 'some-function :after #'some-other-function)
```

My question is, wouldn't be the case to use `#'some-function` in that case?

Of course I tried, and it works, and in fact with the sharp quote, Emacs is able to throw a warning if `some-function` is not defined when I byte-compile the code.

I even tried *advising* aliased functions (with `defalias`) and saw no difference.

So why the common advice is not to use the sharp quote for `SYMBOL` too?

Comment: If `advice-add` behaves like `defadvice` then there's *no need* for `some-function` to be defined when you byte-compile the code. The function will be advised if and when it becomes defined. I guess if you *want* byte-compiler warnings being thrown in the case where the function is not yet defined, then `#'` would be useful.

Comment: @phils That's the case actually, so let's assume that `some-function` is expected to be defined when `advice-add` is evaluated. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: My rule of thumb for when to use `#'` is: use it if and only if `(lambda (args...) (FOO args...))` could be used as well.

Comment: @Stefan so in this case it would be a "no"; `advice-add` wants a symbol and anyway that would advise a (anonymous) wrapper not the function itself, which makes little sense in this context.

Comment: That's right: it takes a symbol and not a function.  As for "adivsing a wrapper" that can't be done: advising is about *modifying* something, so it applies to "generalized variables", aka "lvalues", but not to *values*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `#'foo` is equivalent to `(function foo)` and the documentation states:

> Like ‘quote’, but preferred for objects which are functions.
>   In byte compilation, ‘function’ causes its argument to be compiled.
>   ‘quote’ cannot do that.

IMHO the answer is yes, provided that the function to be *advised* is expected to be defined when the code is byte-compiled.